# Installing imagemagick and rmagick on Lion 10.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I used this link http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-osx.html and now I cannot do brew install imagemagic too..

I did this

**gem install rmagick --version 1.15.17**

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby gem_extconf.rb

sh configure 

Configuring RMagick 1.15.17
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
checking Ruby version... 1.8.7
checking for Magick-config... Magick-config
checking ImageMagick version... 6.7.4
checking for library containing InitializeMagick... no
configure: error: Can't install RMagick. Can't find libMagick or one of the dependent         libraries.
              Check the config.log file for more detailed information.
RMagick configuration failed with status 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before install rmagick, you should install imagemagick ahead.

Can use [brew](https://github.com/jakewins/brew)

```
brew install imagemagick
```

then

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: brew install imagemagic throws an error:     Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.